# Where to get NavUtil Class?

Tags: android

I am looking to use `NavUtils (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html)` in the `v4 android compatibility libraries for Efficency Navigation`. It seems that the **v4 jar does not contain this class**. Further, it seems that NavUtils is not in the master branch of the android support project.

Can anyone tell me how to get NavUtils ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the android-support-v4.jar in your compute is the old version.
so You should update your library. The latest version of support-v4 is 8.

Use Android SDK Manager to checkout the latest version.